# Cakephp v3 Fatal Error with Custom Route class

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to use custom route class.

Sometimes when I redirect to urls like

```
www.site.com/neumaticos-bridgestone
```

it returns Fatal Error.

But when I refresh the page, the error is hidden

I try of implementing many custom route class

routes.php

```php
$routes->connect('/neumaticos-:marca', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'brand'],
     ['routeClass' => 'BrandRoute'])
        ->setPass(['marca']);    
$routes->connect('/neumaticos-para-:slug', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'vehicleVersion'],
     ['routeClass' => 'VehicleVersionRoute'])
        ->setPass(['slug']);
```

BrandRoute.php

```php
namespace Cake\Routing\Route;

use Cake\Utility\Inflector;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\ORM\Query;


class BrandRoute extends Route
{

    public function parse($url, $method = '')
    {
        $params = parent::parse($url, $method);
        if (!$params) {
            return false;
        }
        //return false;
        $brands = TableRegistry::get('ProductBrands');

        $slug = strtolower($params['marca']);
        $brand = $brands->find()
            ->where([
                'ProductBrands.slug' => $slug
            ])
            ->count();
        if($brand > 0){
            return $params;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The fatal error is the next:

```php
Error: Cake\Routing\RouteCollection::parseRequest(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition &quot;Cake\Routing\Route\BrandRoute&quot; of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition 
File /var/www/www.site.com/public_html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/RouteCollection.php 
Line: 205
```

Answer (score 0):

> $routes->connect('/:slug', ['controller' => 'Categories', 'action' =>
>   'view'], ['pass' => ['slug']]);

and the link will be

> $this->Html->link($category->title, ['controller' => 'categories',
>   'action' => 'view', $category->slug]) ?>

Use controller method to split the slug text as category and id etc